# XenServer on i7 Processors?

Tags: virtualization, xen, xenserver, citrix, build-server

Was wondering if anyone is using an i7 XenServer.

Didn't see anything in the HCL on the XenServer site.

If you are using it how is the performance and should I build one on i7 or a older Xeon processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it looks like i7 is supported:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMWcy249Ckw

http://forums.citrix.com/message.jspa?messageID=1465256

Regards,
Port Forward Podcast

Answer (score 0):

You may want to head over to ark.intel.com to look up the "cherry picked" functionality of each processor. That will give you an idea of what a particular Intel processor can and can not do...

Comment: I am building a XenServer as a POC. I just wanted to know if it is capable of running on i7 processors since I have only seen AMD processors and Xeons.

Comment: It comes down to Xen's requirements vs. the particular capabilities of the specific Intel model (based on what is enabled and/or disabled). Do you have a specific model in mind?

Answer (score 0):

i7 Has VTx, so you can use them for xenserver if you want to. I have friends running Xenserver  on Debian. It runs very smoothly.